# List to Dictionary with incremental keys in one line LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq, list, dictionary

I have this list:

```
var items = new List<string>() { "Hello", "I am a value", "Bye" };
```

I want it to convert it to a dictionary with the following structure:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<int, string>()
{
     { 1, "Hello" },
     { 2, "I am a value" },
     { 3, "Bye" }
};
```

As you can see, the dictionary keys are just incremental values, but they should also reflect the positions of each element in the list.

I am looking for a **one-line** LINQ statement. Something like this:

```
var dic = items.ToDictionary(i => **Specify incremental key or get element index**, i => i);
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do that by using the overload of [`Enumerable.Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534869(v=vs.100).aspx) which passes the index of the element:

```
var dic = items.Select((val, index) => new { Index = index, Value = val})
               .ToDictionary(i => i.Index, i => i.Value);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Didn't know the `Select` method could give me an extra argument with the element's index!

Comment: oh, I thought he was looking for 1 linq statement. +1

Comment: @KhanhTO But this is a LINQ statement.

Answer (score 3):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var items = new List<string>() { "Hello", "I am a value", "Bye" };
    int i = 1;
    var dict = items.ToDictionary(A => i++, A => A);

    foreach (var v in dict)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(v.Key + "   " + v.Value);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();    
}
```

Output

```
1   Hello
2   I am a value
3   Bye
```

EDIT: Out of curosity i did a performance test with a list of 3 million strings.

1st Place: Simple For loop to add items to a dictionary using the loop count as the key value. (Time: 00:00:00.2494029)

2nd Place: This answer using a integer variable outside of LINQ. Time(00:00:00.2931745)

3rd Place: Yuval Itzchakov's Answer doing it all on a single line. Time (00:00:00.7308006)

Comment: Is that an one-line Linq statement?

Comment: @Luïs: it may be more efficient

Comment: @Luïs Technically yes, though the need for an incrementor isn't required as referenced by Yuval's nice answer.

Comment: @Luïs I suppose technically its not because of the int declaration however its much simpler.

Comment: dont get mad for one line `int i = 1;` @Luïs

Comment: I don't think using a separate variable and a lambda statement with side-effects is *much simpler* than using the LINQ method made specifically to do this...

Comment: @Rawling: Maybe a simple loop is better as it's more efficient

Comment: @KhanhTO That's even further from a one-line LINQ statement.

Answer (score -1):

```
var items = new List<string>() { "Hello", "I am a value", "Bye" };
```

**solution #1**:

```
var dic2 = items.Select((item, index) => new { index, item })
                .ToDictionary(x => x.item, x => x.index);
```

**solution #2**:

```
int counter = 0;
var dic = items.ToDictionary(x => x, z => counter++);
```